# How do I iterate a nested dictionary with string formatting?

Tags: python, dictionary

I checked a few other posts and either they didn't contain the information I need or I didn't understand them. I want to make this program print the sentence for every entry in the nested dictionary, and maybe also make a function to do this as well (not familiar with these yet).

I know it will use a `for` loop but what I can't figure out is how to configure the keys(?).

```
people = {
    1: {
        'name': 'David Wallace',
        'age': 50,
        'occupation': 'CFO',
        'ethnicity': 'American',
        'location': 'New York'
    },
    2: {
        'name': 'Michael',
        'age': 42,
        'occupation': 'Regional Manager',
        'ethnicity': 'American',
        'location': 'Scranton, Pennsylvania'
    },
    3: {
        'name': 'Jim',
        'age': 27,
        'occupation': 'Sales Rep',
        'ethnicity': 'American',
        'location': 'Scranton, Pennsylvania'
    }
}
print('{name} is a {age} year-old {ethnicity} {occupation} from {location}.'.format(**people))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really treating the top-level dict more like a list, so you can write a for loop traversing the top-level like so:

```py
people = {
    1: {
        'name': 'David Wallace',
        'age': 50,
        'occupation': 'CFO',
        'ethnicity': 'American',
        'location': 'New York'
    },
    2: {
        'name': 'Michael',
        'age': 42,
        'occupation': 'Regional Manager',
        'ethnicity': 'American',
        'location': 'Scranton, Pennsylvania'
    },
    3: {
        'name': 'Jim',
        'age': 27,
        'occupation': 'Sales Rep',
        'ethnicity': 'American',
        'location': 'Scranton, Pennsylvania'
    }
}

for person in people.values():
    print('{name} is a {age} year-old {ethnicity} {occupation} from {location}.'.format(**person))
```

The full reference for Python dictionaries is here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items

Edit: Thanks to user Chris Charley for the suggestion to use `people.values()` instead of `people.items()`

Comment: You could also have stated `for person in people.values():`